# Started rails server but localhost:3000 shows error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently following the tutorials on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. I 'm at section 5 when I tried running the server and go to localhost:3000 but this error shows up ([link to screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtTUw.png))

Answer (score 0):

According to the image you uploaded, it seems that you forgot to add `show` method in `EventsController`.

Try to add in your events_controller.rb file:

```
def show
end
```